# How can I call forward in action helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

In a normal action, I do this `$this->_forward()`. I want to do the same thing in an action helper. This doesn't work

```
$this->getActionController()->_forward('');
$this->_actionController()->_forward('');
```

Comment: Have you tried $this->_forward() ?

Comment: A call to _forward($action, $controller) changes the request object and runs through the dispatch cycle again. Can you give some idea on why you want to use forward within an action helper?

Answer (score 1):

_forward is a protected function so obviously you can't call it via

```
$this->getActionController()->_forward('');
```

The easiest way to make the forward method usable in a public scope is to make a new forward() method (note 'forward' not '_forward) and proxy it to the _forward method:

```
class App_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null)
    {
        return $this->_forward($action, $controller, $module, $params);
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it, but it should work
Happy hacking.

Comment: Should be able to override `_forward()` directly since the move from protected to public _expands_ the visibility.

Comment: _forward is a final protected function so unless you want to change the source of your local copy of the framework, you cannot do that

Comment: D'oh! Absolutely right, I didn't realize that `_forward()` was listed as `final`. Thanks for the heads up.